# jQuery using.Map to build Alphabetical array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey Im doing something like this:

```
temp = $.map(response, function(item) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.id
            };
        });
        temp.unshift({label: "", value: 0});temp
```

Is there a way to make sure the return is built in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always sort the `response` prior to creating the map or simply sort the resulting mapped array.

```
var response = [{ name: 'z', id: 1 }, { name: 'a', id: 2 }];

response = response.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name < b.name? -1 : +(a.name > b.name);
});

response[0].name; //a
```

Please note that `+(a.name > b.name)` is used to explicitely return `0` when equal and `1` when greater, since that's what the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function expects.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
});

var result = temp.map(function(e){
    return list[e.index]
});
```